# GWT: forward user to a URL

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, jsni

Really simple question: From within GWT I want to forward the user away from my GWT page to a certain URL. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a native method:

```
public static native void setWindowHref(String url)/*-{
        $wnd.location.href = url;

}-*/;
```

This would set the current browser URL to be the address you specify.

---

Alternative with GWT's API (thanks, Hilbrand):

```
Window.Location.assign(url);
```

Comment: GWT already has a static method for this: Location.assign(String newURL) (in the Window class).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static native void leavePage() /*-{
   $wnd.location.href = "http://www.certainurl.com/";
}-*/;
```